# Ruby Rspec Keep getting NoMethodError for Nil class

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to Ruby and am just learning RSpec. I've written a test for a certain method and keep getting the failing test error:

```
Failure/Error: if @board[5][@move - 1] == EMPTY_CIRCLE

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

I know that the code in the Class file does actually work as it should but I just can't seem to get the test to pass.

Here is the Class file code:

```
class ConnectFour   
    attr_accessor :player_one, :player_two, :move, :current_player, :board

EMPTY_CIRCLE = "\e[37m\u25cb".freeze
YELLOW_CIRCLE = "\u001b[33m\u25cf".freeze
RED_CIRCLE = "\u001b[31m\u25cf".freeze

def initialize
        @board = Array.new(6){Array.new(7,EMPTY_CIRCLE)}
        @player_one = nil  
        @player_two = nil               
end

def play_round
        print_board
        prompt_player
        @move = prompt_move
        place_marker                    
end

def prompt_move
    loop do
      @move = gets.chomp.to_i
      return @move if valid_move?(@move)

      puts "Invalid input. Enter a column number between 1 and 7"           
    end
end

def valid_move?(move)
    @move.is_a?(Integer) && @move.between?(1, 7)
end

    def place_marker
        if @board[5][@move - 1] == EMPTY_CIRCLE
            @board[5][@move - 1] = @current_player.marker
        end
    end
end
```

And here is the RSpec test code:

```
describe ConnectFour do
  subject(:game) { described_class.new }
    let(:player){ double(Player) }

describe '#place_marker' do
        context 'when column is empty' do
            before do
                move = 4                
                allow(game).to receive(:move).and_return(4)
            end

            it 'places marker on bottom row' do                         
                game.place_marker
                expect{game.place_marker}.to change{@board[5][3]}   
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I've tried multiple things but just can't get the test method to recognize the value for @move i'm trying to send it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!.

Comment: When I ran your code the error came from the line `game.place_marker` in your test. The offending code is when you call the `-` method on `@move`. `@move` is nil because it is never assigned. A simple `puts @move.inspect` in the line above where it fails would have told you this. I'd suggest trying some basic debugging before your next post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@move` is nil. You're stubbing out a `move` method (that doesn't seem to exist) to return `4`, but this has nothing to do with the `@move` variable.

Either make sure `@move` is set, or modify your code so that it actually has a `move` method and that all direct reads to `@move` instead use this method, so your stub can work.

Comment: Could I stub the prompt_move method and set @move that way?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out how to set @move. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can stub @move attr_accessor to return a value:

```
allow(game).to receive(:move=).with(move: 2)
```